# How to get rid of the language symbol?

Tags: unity, notification

Migrated from 12.10 to 13.10 a couple of days ago. 
I speak English, British English. I have a British layout keyboard. Now I have a square symbol in the top bar (or whatever it's proper name is) with En1 in and when I click on that there is an En2 (American English).

Migration took two attempts. The first was via the Upgrade path straight from 12.10 which meant I kept all my settings and files and folders (or so I thought). However I was obliged to bin the whole lot and essentially start again when I discovered that during the upgrade Ubuntu didn't recognize my keyboard correctly - I no longer had a "£", and instead of @ I received " when typing in my email address (!!)
At this time I noticed the En language symbol in the top bar.

I binned the OS and thereafter I downloaded 13.10 straight from Ubuntu, burned to disc, loaded on.

Keyboard working now as it should BUT language symbol still there.

Is it (the language symbol) supposed to be there?  If not, how to I get rid of it? (And I don't want to have to go through the whole carry-on of rubbing stuff off and reloading stuff back on again which takes up more time than I care to mention. If  have to live with the thing sitting there doing nothing I *will* do ...)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's there so that you can switch keyboard layouts. I often switch between English and Norwegian, for instance. I don't really understand why that menu is a problem, but if you want it to go away, have a look in the System Settings. I don't remember what it's called in English, but it's one of the entries on the top row and the setting is at the bottom of the screen, "Show current input in the panel" or something like that.

By the way; you keep all your settings if you keep your home directory.

Comment: It's the "Text Entry" capplet in System Settings.

Comment: Thanks very much chaps for the explanations. Text entry settings - bin the English US and untick the "Show in menu bar box" = symbol gone. Perfect.   :0)